# Depending source for drop down list

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have one drop down list in my pages that its source comes of below code. Now I like to put 1 text box adjusted on my drop down list and when I type on that,  source of drop down list (DocumentNo) depend on what I type in the text box and when text box is null drop downs list shows all the (DocumentNo)  , please help how I have to change my code,

```
protected void ddlProjectDocument_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        var query = from p in _DataContext.tblDocuments
                    orderby p.DocumentNo
                    select p;
        int maxs = 0;
        foreach (tblDocument v in query)
        {
            if (v.DocumentNo.Length > maxs)
                maxs = v.DocumentNo.Length;
        }

        foreach (tblDocument vv in query)
        {
            string doctitle = vv.DocumentNo;
            for (int i = vv.DocumentNo.Length; i < maxs; i++)
            {
                doctitle += "&nbsp;";

            }
            doctitle += "&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
            doctitle += vv.TITLE;
            // Use HtmlDecode to correctly show the spaces
            doctitle = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(doctitle);
            ddlProjectDocument.Items.Add(new ListItem(doctitle, vv.DocId.ToString()));


        }



    }
```

Comment: Which UI Framework are you using (WebForms, MVC, WinForms, etc.)?

Comment: i use web forms, just i like to type in drop down list and it changes source depend of my value, i do not know maybe i have to use another control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would highly recommend storing the result of that query at the beginning of the method into something like a session variable so that you don't have to continually query the database every time you hit this page.

Second, you should use the [OnTextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx) event in ASP.NET to solve this problem. Put in the OnTextChanged attribute to point to a method in your code behind that will grab the query result values (now found in your session variable) and will reset what is contained in `ddlProjectDocument.Items` to anything that matched what was being written by using `String.StartsWith()`:

```
var newListOfThings = queryResults.Where(q => q.DocumentNo.StartsWith(MyTextBox.Value));
```

At this point all you need to do is do that same loop that you did at the end of the method above to introduce the correct formatting.